# Randomly switch between parked domains after each page refresh

Tags: php

Suppose i have the main domain 1.com and two parked domains of 2.com, 3.com. Now, how to randomly switch between each of the parked and main domains on each page refresh. how can this task done effectively? i am using php.

e.g. when the page is loaded for the first time, address bar is 2.com (it is selected randomly and can also be 1.com or 3.com), know if i refresh the page, the address bar will be 1.com (again, it can also be 2.com or 3.com), and so on..

Comment: `"Switch between each of the parked and main domains"` - as in redirect to the different domains?

Comment: maybe... each refresh should redirect to a randomly selected domain.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be running them in a never ending loop once they reached each of the said domains? Or is the only redirecting happening on the main domain?

Comment: yes unfortunately i realized the never ending loop! i need the redirection occur in all domains..

Comment: @diapson Yeah it's a killer isn't it. Why don't you redirect users after `X seconds` or after a user based event like a form submission, button click, etc etc..

Comment: it's a project for a domain reseller.. they want visitor redirect to their domains randomly when they visit his main website! but it was really interesting fact for me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using a plain php site then it would become some work but I can think of two ways,

In either cases you need a function that generates those domains dynamically

```
<?php
    getDomain(){
        $domains = array('example.com','example2.com', 'example3.com');
        return $domains[mt_rand(0,count($domains)-1)];
    }
?>
```

1. Either create all links on the page as relative links then add a base tag on the top of the page which is generated dynamically.

   ```
   <head><base href="<?= getDomain() ?>"></head>
   ```

   This way all relative links will be written relative to that base, this is the easier method but it's not really what I would recommend.
2. Second method I would suggest is creating a function that creates all the links, or handle it manually if you don't want to create an extra function, for example:

   Instead of doing this

   ```
   <a href = 'http://mydomain.com/some/uri'>Go here</a>
   ```

   You would write it something like this

   ```
   <a href = '<?= getDomain() ?>/some/uri'>Go here</a>
   ```

   Or create a URL generating function

   ```
   <?php
       generateLink($uri){
            return getDomain().$uri;
       }
   ?>
   ```

   Then call it like this

   ```
   <a href = '<?= generateLink('/some/uri') ?>'>Go here</a>
   ```

   Keep in mind that not all links on the same page would have the same domain, you need to handle that your self if you want all links to point to the same domain in each request.

Of course the whole thing is just messy, but then the feature it self is strange so I don't expect any thing much cleaner to do this.

Comment: thanks.. but this is not the case. it's about how to work with links when domain changes. the main problem is how to change the domains themselves?

Comment: do you want the actual domain to change, or just the content of the page ?

Comment: No, the actual domain at address bar should be changed.